Do $\operatorname{arcsec}\left(\frac{2x}{5x+3}\right)$ and $\operatorname{arccos}\left(\frac{5x+3}{2x}\right)$ have the same domain?
Do $$f(x)=\operatorname{arcsec}\left(\frac{2x}{5x+3}\right) \quad\text{and}\quad g(x) = \operatorname{arccos}\left(\frac{5x+3}{2x}\right)$$ have the same domain? I wondered about this while finding the domain of $f(x).$
I found the domain of $g(x)$ to be $\left[-1, \frac{-3}{7}\right]$ and the domain of $f(x)$ to be $\left[-1,\frac{-3}{7}\right] - \left\{\frac{-3}{5}\right\}.$
What is my mistake in my conversion of $f$ to $g,$ or in how I obtained the two different domains?

Remember when $x=-0.6$, $\dfrac{2x}{5x+3}$ is undefined so $\text{arcsec}\dfrac{2x}{5x+3}$ is also undefined,


$$f(x)=\operatorname{arcsec}\left(\frac{2x}{5x+3}\right) \quad\text{and}\quad g(x) = \operatorname{arccos}\left(\frac{5x+3}{2x}\right).$$
I found the domain of $f(x)$ to be $\left[-1,\frac{-3}{7}\right] -
 \left\{\frac{-3}{5}\right\},$ and the domain of $g(x)$ to be $\left[-1, \frac{-3}{7}\right].$

This is correct. $\operatorname{arcsec}\left(\frac1y\right)$ and $\arccos(y)$ have different maximal domains.

What is my mistake in my conversion of $f$ to $g$ ?

You haven't made a mistake here either: $f$ and $g$ are indeed identically equal, and this just means that they are equal wherever they are both defined. Notice that the identity $$\operatorname{arcsec}\left(\frac1y\right)\equiv\arccos(y)$$ has domain $[-1,1]\color\red{-\{0\}}.$ At $y=0,$ although $\arccos(y)$ is defined, this identity is inapplicable.
P.S. On the other hand, the identity $$\operatorname{arcsec}(x)\equiv\arccos\left(\frac1x\right)$$ has domain $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty),$ and $\operatorname{arcsec}(x)$ and $\arccos\left(\frac1x\right)$ have the same maximal domain.
